# react native reanimated carousel AOS Touch Slide Issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, carousel, react-native-reanimated

I've been struggling with this for a few days and I'm asking for help here.
When I use react native reanimated carousel inside a TabView in react native, the carousel can only slide with two fingers in AOS, not one.
On IOS, the carousel works fine. I really want to solve this problem. Is there any way?

```
TabView component

 <View style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: COLORS.def_background,
            }}>

                <View style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    marginHorizontal: 7, marginTop: 20,
                }}>
                    <TabView
                        navigationState={this.state}
                        swipeEnabled={false}
                        renderScene={SceneMap({
                            first: () => <NewsBreaking navigation={this.props.navigation} />,
                            second: () => <NewsLatest navigation={this.props.navigation}/>, 
                                        // Here's a carousel inside a component
                            third: () => <NewsMost navigation={this.props.navigation}/>,
                        })}
                        onIndexChange={index => this.setState({index})}
                        initialLayout={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}
                        renderTabBar={this._renderTabBar}
                        gestureHandlerProps={{
                            onGestureEvent: () => {}, // 빈 함수를 사용하여 터치 동작을 비활성화합니다.
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
```

```
 NewsLatest component
 return <FlatList
            keyExtractor={item => item._id}
            data={this.state.listData}
            // onEndReached={this.moreList}
            // onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
            ListHeaderComponent={() => {
// here
                return (<LatestCarousel listData={this.state.listData.slice(0, 3)} navigation={this.props.navigation}/>)
            }}
```

```
 panGestureHandlerProps={{
                    activeOffsetX: [-10, 0],
                }}
```

I've tried it and haven't found any issues on the official GitHub where there is a workaround